# CURL multipart - issue with the parameters

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, curl

I should upload an mp4 file onto datastore and for this reason I've added the following method on my appengine:

```
def set_video():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return '''
        <!doctype html>
        <title>Upload video</title>
        <h1>Upload video</h1>
        <form method="POST"
             action=""
             role="form"
             enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <p><input type=file name=Video.mp4>
             <input type=submit value=Upload>
        </form>
        '''
    else:
        file = request.files['Video.mp4']
        if _file:
            cloud_file = cloudstorage.open(BUCKET_NAME + "video." + _file.filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1],
             mode='w', content_type=_file.mimetype)
             _file.save(cloud_file)
             cloud_file.close()
        return "Success"
```

If I use the post-multipart objectof LabVIEW everything works well, and I'm able to store a new video. But, using CURL I've encountered an issue: it seems like I'm not able to set the parameters of multipart.
I've used the following command:

```
curl -include --form name=Video.mp4  --form upload=@Video.mp4 -A "National Instruments LabVIEW" http://MY_URL -0
```

where I've used the same User-Agent of LabVIEW.
Sniffing the communication with wireshark I can see this:

```
Encapsulated multipart part:  (application/octet-stream)
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="Video.mp4"\r\n
    mime_multipart.header.content-type
```

So, the 'name' parameter is "upload" instead of "Video.mp4" as in the LabVIEW version:

```
Encapsulated multipart part:  (application/octet-stream)
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Video.mp4"; filename="Video.mp4"\r\n
    Content-Type: video/mpeg\r\n\r\n
```

Can anybody say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using a single `--form` with semicolon-separated settings, e.g `--form "name=Video.mp4; upload=@Video.mp4"`?

Comment: Hi Daniel and thanks for your attention. I've tried as you suggested but it still didn't work. But from your suggestion I found the solution:
`curl --form "Video.mp4=@Video.mp4" LINK `
Indeed as can be seen from my previous post, in my first solution (`upload=@Video.mp4`) the name of the file is the string  present before '='.